# Remain spaces and newline chars during article sanitization

Tags: php, regex, string, char

I try to create something like sanitize article function. I mean a function that cleans or normalizes content of articles that are displayed in html blog sites.

It must remove all whitespaces except `\n` and . So newline and space.

I started an idea to encode newlines and spaces by addcslashes php function. Then remove all whitespace occurrences. Then use stripslashes. Then replace multiple `\x20` occurrences with single ones. So it would be something like newline chars and spaces temporary hibernation for regex operation.

But I did not succeed cause the output has no newline char that does exist in the input.

Online version https://ideone.com/I4oZCJ

My code that does not work:

```
<?php
    $text = 'first line
second line';
    $text = addcslashes($text, "\x20\t");
    $text = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $text);
    $text = stripslashes($text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $text);
    var_dump($text);
```

How to get it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the horizontal whitespace characters using the `\h` class:

```
preg_replace('/\h+/', ' ', $text');
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/FqS2g9)

Alternatively, you could create a character class of your own, excluding all characters you *don't* want to replace:

```
 preg_replace('/[^\S\n]+/', ' ', $text);
```

Basically, this matches all chacters that are NOT `\S` (non-whitespace) and not `\n` (no newline chars). Both work.

Comment: I used these patterns. The CR whitespace, I mean `\r`, was replaced by space. It should have been removed. You can see it online: https://ideone.com/ebP1Q4

Comment: @trzczy call `str_replace("\r", '', $text)` first then, remove the characters that you want to remove as quickly and easily as possible

Comment: But "\r" is not the only vertical whitespace that "\h" ignores. The filter should be "each \s except space and \n". The investigation is to normalize an article invisible chars to let strlen count visible chars.

Answer (score 0):

https://ideone.com/hJrH8R

```
<?php
function clean($text) {
    $text = preg_replace('/[\cK\f\r\x85]+/', '', $text);
    $text = preg_replace('/\h+/', ' ', $text);
    return  $text;
}
```